# HTML Checkbox with JQuery (uncheck others and attr)

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

Im working at register page where u have the option to choose between Personal or Business account. I don't know how to solve this problem.
I've wrote some JQuery and kind a work but it dosnt.
The attributes changes Works, but only happens one time. I can select "Personal" then "Business" and after that radiobuttons dont work anymore.

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($("#tipoUsuario").on("click", function(){
        if ($($(".esEmpresa")).is(":checked")){
            $(".esUsuario").attr("checked", false);
            $("#divUsuario").hide();
            $("#apellidos").attr("required", false);
            $("#nombres").attr("required", false);
            $("#divEmpresa").show();
            $("#nombreEmpresa").attr("required", true);
            $("#cuitEmpresa").attr("required", true);
        } else if ($($(".esUsuario")).is(":checked")) {
            $(".esEmpresa").attr("checked", false)
            $(".esUsuario").attr("checked", true);
            $("#divUsuario").show();
            $("#nombreEmpresa").attr("required", false);
            $("#cuitEmpresa").attr("required", false);
            $("#divEmpresa").hide();
            $("#apellidos").attr("required", true);
            $("#nombres").attr("required", true);
        };
    }));
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tipoUsuario" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-b-10">
        <p class="text-muted font-13"> Seleccioná el tipo de cuenta: </p>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="esUsuario" name="esUsuario" value=False type="radio" class="esUsuario custom-control-input">
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description">Personal</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="esEmpresa" name="esEmpresa" value=True type="radio" class="esEmpresa custom-control-input">
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description">Empresa</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typically radio buttons that are exclusionary of each other share the same name.....

Comment: take a look at button groups http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio , then combine it with this tabs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

just use the same name for both radio buttons and they will behave according to your requirement. No need to add additional js.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

Changed the names as @Sinha said, and used a different way to check if radio buttons are checked on if statement

Thanks everybody

HTML:

```
<div id="tipoUsuario" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 m-b-10">
        <p class="text-muted font-13"> Seleccioná el tipo de cuenta: </p>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="esEmpresa" name="esEmpresa" value="no" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description">Personal</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input id="esEmpresa" name="esEmpresa" value="si" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                <span class="custom-control-description">Empresa</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#tipoUsuario").on("change", function(){
    if ($('input[name="esEmpresa"]:checked').val() == "si"){
        $("#divUsuario").hide();
        $("#apellidos").attr("required", false);
        $("#nombres").attr("required", false);
        $("#divEmpresa").show();
        $("#nombreEmpresa").attr("required", true);
        $("#cuitEmpresa").attr("required", true);
    }else{
        $("#divUsuario").show();
        $("#nombreEmpresa").attr("required", false);
        $("#cuitEmpresa").attr("required", false);
        $("#divEmpresa").hide();
        $("#apellidos").attr("required", true);
        $("#nombres").attr("required", true);
};
});
```